# Arbitrary distortion of cyclic subgroups of solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated solvable group, and let $H$ be an infinite cyclic subgroup of $G$. What possible functions may arise as the subgroup distortion of $H$ in $G$?

For polycyclic groups, Osin and others have studied this question. However, I am specifically interested in finitely generated solvable non-polycyclic groups of finite rank. If this is already known, any possible references would be much appreciated.

Thank you for any possible answers.

Comment: For polycyclic groups, it follows from early results of Guivarch 1973 (and other using embedding as lattices, covered in Raghunathan's book) that the distortion of cyclic subgroups is $n^d$ for some integer $d\ge 1$, or exponential. More recent results of Osin concern more general subgroups than cyclic subgroups.

Comment: "of finite rank": do you mean finite Prüfer rank? please specify. "rank" has (too) many meanings.

Comment: Here, I mean the following. For a finitely generated $G$ with finitely generated subgroup $H$, we set $r(H)$ as the minimum cardinality of a finite generating subset for $H$ and set $rank(G)$ as the maximum of the value $r(H)$ as we range over all finitely generated subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Yes, this is finite Prüfer rank. The question for arbitrary finitely generated solvable groups and for finite Prüfer rank are of independent interest and have probably dramatically different answers. Which one do you choose here?

Comment: I am interested in the question for finitely generated solvable groups in general, but for the time being, lets restrict ourselves to finite Prüfer rank finitely generated solvable groups.

Comment: For f.g. solv. groups of finite Prüfer rank, I think that the answer is the same as for polycyclic groups. For arbitrary f.g. solvable groups I would guess there's no restriction (i.e., that the same distortion as in any f.g. group can be achieved), but I'm not sure it's known.

Comment: The solvable Baumslag group BS(1,2) has exponential distortion for a cyclic subgroup. .